# Unable to get traceId for error logs in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-logback

Have enabled traceId in our springboot application by adding following dependencies, and application is deployed in kubernetes setup, However traceId is available only for info logs, incase of error logs we could not find the traceId, Log level is set to info in our application.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!-- Adding Micrometer registry for prometheus -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Adding sleuth library dependency for traceIds -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```